# .Net - How to export and install a Custom scaffold vsix extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I wrote a custom scaffolding extension for my project using this tutorial

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/03/creating-a-custom-scaffolder-for-visual-studio.aspx

It's my first time building my own vsix extension, the extension runs in an experimental instance and does exactly what I want.

How do I export this vsix so that I can use it in my other projects?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the page you linked to, there is a link on this very subject.

> Deploying your Scaffolder to the VSIX gallery - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff363239.aspx (make sure to have the category type as Tools->Scaffolding, as that will allow it to be more discoverable to end-users)

Comment: Do you know where the vsix file gets built to?

Comment: If you setup your project with a `.vsixmanifest`, the `.visx` file will be output to the `bin` directory. See [this sample project](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VSIX-Deployable-Single-ee39e3fe).

Comment: Awesome thanks mate, any chance you know how to escape angled brackets in t4 templates? I need to have <summary> in a comment but the t4 templater thinks it is the start of a directive